# Override `npm install` script for NPM project

Tags: node.js, npm

I have an NPM project, when `npm install` is run, I'd like to run a custom script.

I tried using this in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "install": "./scripts/install.sh",   // <<<<
 },
```

but that actually just resulted in an infinite loop.
The reason I am looking for this, is because there are tools that simply call `npm install`, so I can't control what they run. Otherwise, if I had control, I would just call `./scripts/install.sh` myself instead.

Note that this is probably not the best idea, just curious if it's possible.

Note my install script looks something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export FOO="bar";
export PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD="true";

npm install
```

Comment: Have you tried "postinstall": "yourScript" ?

Comment: Unfortunately modifying postinstall won't work for my use case, since I need to set some env variables for my install script. I think a preinstall script might work, if the env variables for my pre-install script were used by install as well?

Comment: Yes, sorry you need preinstall, yes I think environment variables will be persisted for install as well, give it a try.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `preinstall` to run code before `npm install`. Don't try to override `npm install` in this fashion where you would end up with an infinite loop of calls to `npm install`.

You can also set environment variables using the `config` property of `package.json`. See [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#configuration) for details

Comment: For those that find this answer, it's `preinstall` - https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

Comment: this is not a valid answer anymore since NPM@7. `preinstall` and `postinstall` happens after `install`.