# I need to add dependency in my package.json and load module , after taking user input while running npm install

Tags: node.js, node-modules, package.json

I need to add a dependency in my package.json  and load module, by taking user input in command prompt while running npm install.

Is it possible to do so.

Comment: we install the dependencies from the command prompt only. how you insall the dependencies? can you please explain more!

Comment: @RaviSingh I need to download some dependency conditionally.

Like we have "Dependency A" and "Dependency B", I need to ask the user a question on CLI  and accordingly dependency will get downloaded.

Comment: @AshishKanojia, did my answer help you or do you need an example script?

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't provided much information about what exactly you try to accomplish, it's difficult to advise you or give a concrete example. Anyhow, in `package.json`, you can override the default behavior of [npm scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) with the `scripts` field:

```
"scripts": {
    "install": "./scripts/install.sh",
}
```

As someone else has [noted before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48859022/12917821), you cannot call `npm install` in your custom script, though, as this would lead to infinite recursion. Thus, rather provide a `preinstall` script, which `npm` runs before `install`.

For use cases other than adding dependencies based on user input, I recommend to check how to set the [environment variables and configurations](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#environment), which the user then could override with `npm config set project-name:config-name config-value`.